# Компиляция исходника на Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7, компоненты

По работе мне необходимо внести несколько правок в программу написанную на Delphi 7 в 2003 году. Исходник есть, но я не могу его скомпилировать. При компиляции выясняется что Delphi нехватает кучи компонентов. Часть необходимых компонентов я нашел и установил, где брать другие я не представляю. С исходниками идет парочка dll, могу ли подключить dll вместо установки всех зависимостей в Delphi?

Comment: Конечно можете. Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

dll следует просто хранить в папке с конечным exe-файлом. В случае с Delphi 7 это папка с проектом

Comment: Так как мне этот проект скомпилировать если не все компоненты получается найти?

Comment: Никак. Либо найти все компоненты, либо вырезать из исходников все что связано с компонентами, которых у вас нет

Comment: Этого я и боялся, на работе сделана самописная программка которая выгружает данные платежки в базу данных, щас поменялось законодательство, добавилось доп.поле на платежку...а без перекомпиляции ничего не сделать.